# how to get total opacity for sticky navbar to the top using locomotive-scroll?

Tags: html, css, locomotive-scroll

How to make background fully opaque? I have managed to stick main to the top but it's background is invisible.

***HTML***

```
<main>
  <div data-scroll-container>
    <div class="bg">
      <h1 data-scroll-sticky>Hey</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

***CSS***

```
.bg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

***Javascript***

```
const locoScroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
  el: document.querySelector("main"),
  smooth: true
});
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

***HTML***

```
<main>
  <div class="bg" id="menu" data-scroll-sticky>
    <h1>Menu</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="section-1" data-scroll-section></div>
  <div id="section-2" data-scroll-section></div>
</main>
```

***CSS***

```
#menu {
  background-color: brown;
  min-height: 10dvh;
  position: sticky;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
#section-1 {
  background-color: orange;
  min-height: 100dvh;
}
#section-2 {
  background-color: brown;
  min-height: 100dvh;
}
```

***Javascript***

```
const locoScroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
  el: document.querySelector("main"),
  smooth: true
});
```